# How to add imageView down the TabBar in TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

[image]I want to add a imageView below/down the TabBar in TabBarController is there any way to do that. I searched a lot got one answer about adding the TabBarController in other ViewController's container view and add that image down that container view. I also try to add image programmatically but it covers the TabBar. 
So how can i do that any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: TabBarController in other ViewController's container view and add that image down that container view. Is that fix your issue?

Comment: Below solution is helpful for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one custom class inherit it from UITabarController and use the following code

```
class CustomTabbarController: UITabBarController {

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height - 10, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 10))
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red // set image you wanted to show
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
                tabBar.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - 60 // change it according to your requirement
    }

}
```

Now set the custom class to the Tabbarcontroller inside storyboard
[image]